# Power path sharing with LTC4416

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, integrated-circuit, power-electronics

I am struggling with the [LTC4416 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4416fa.pdf). My need is a 4-cell Li-Po battery (13.6..17.2V) used as the device battery and an optional external power supply (18..24V). When the external power is applied, it is used. Otherwise, the battery will be used.

As I need to prevent external power to charge the battery and the battery voltage flow in the external power connector. I need to power path with MOSFETs.

I found the LTC4416 which looks good. My application is clearly "V1 is Greater Than V2", but I don't understand the datasheet. Here is the application schema with the sentence that confuses me.

As `nE2` is shortened to `GND`, `G2` will be always powered. So `Q3` is useless. I think that I am misunderstanding how this IC works. `G2` should be somehow disabled, but I don't understand how.

[image: Figure 3 from LTC4416 datasheet]

- **V1** is the external power supply.
- **V2** is the battery.

The block diagram isn't that clear because the two "Analog Controller" take both EN1 and EN2.

[image: Internal block diagram from LTC4416 datasheet]

How is `Q3` disabled when `Q1` and `Q2` are enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *As nE2 is shortened to GND, G2 will be always powered.*

That is incorrect. Page 5 of [DS](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4416fa.pdf): -

> *\$\overline{E2}\$ (Pin 4): LTC4416 Comparator Enable Input. A low
> signal less than VREF will enable the V2 path. The ideal diode action
> will then determine if the V2 path should turn on by controlling any
> PFET(s) connected to the G2 pin.*

"It" enables "the path" but, it only enables G2 if the other logic allows it. That other logic allows this to happen when the primary supply drops below 12 volts. If you look at your 2nd picture, EN1 has an input into the 2nd analogue controller and, if high, it will disable G2.

Comment: No, it's not explicit so, you have to take it as read and trust them.